# Is any algebraic number a root of a given orthogonal polynomial?

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

Let $S=\left\{P_n(x)\right\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be any sequence of $n$-degree polynomials which are orthogonal in the interval $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}$. If $\xi$ is an arbitrary algebraic number such that $a<\xi<b$, then, is true that we can always find a finite positive integer $m$ such that $P_m(\xi)=0$?

Comment: Are you thinking about polynomials with rational coefficients?

Comment: Hi Crostul. I'm thinking if, given an arbitrary sequence of orthogonal polynomials on the real line, if every real algebraic number is a root of some polynomial belonging to this sequence. I look for the most general answer, but any comment about special cases (for instance, when the polynomials have rational coefficients) is welcome as well. Thanks!

Comment: Can I pick the set of polynomials, e.g. the Chebyshev polynomials?  So, is every algebraic number a root of one of these?  I have not looked yet but it seems rather unlikely.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: Looking further, I see that the roots of the Chebyshev polynomials have a name: Chebysehv nodes.  So, are all algebraic numbers Chebyshev nodes?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes

Comment: I think that this question depends on whether the set of all roots of all orthogonal polynomials in a giving sequence is a dense set, but I'm not sure of that...

Comment: Chebyshev nodes are surely a dense set, but they don't contain all algebraic numbers.

Comment: Thank you badjohn and Ivan Neretin. It seems that the answer to this problem is therefore negative. However, can someone give an example of a real algebraic number which is not of the form of a Chebyshev node, or explain in some more detail why the Chebyshev nodes do not countain all real algebraic numbers in the interval (-1,1)?

Comment: $1/2$ is not a root of any Chebyshev polynomial. Its $\arccos(1/2)=\pi/3$, which is not a multiple of $\pi$ by a rational number for which $2$ divides the denominator. The roots of the Chebyshev are cosines of $\pi\cdot \frac{2k-1}{2n}$. Notice how that $2$ factor of the $2n$ doesn't cancel, since $2k-1$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you LB_O. This closes the question as it was stated. I will write an answer from the comments. Thank you for all. Now going further: we can easily prove as well that this conjecture is false for any sequence of orthogonal polynomials whose true interval of orthogonality (the smallest interval which contains all roots of the orthogonal polynomials) is smaller than the interval of orthogonality: just pick an algebraic number lying outside the true interval of orthogonality but inside the interval of orthogonality...